# JSP textarea length check issues

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have tried to use some of the max length functions found here, but I am running into some issues with them. I have tried to check the length of the form when the user presses a submit button, but the value in the variable does not change until the form is being submitted. Below is the relevant code:

```
<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Comments:</b><br>
<form:textarea path="currentProjTask.comments" id="currComments" cols="100" rows="10" /></td>
</tr>
```

Below is the code that creates a popup. The value will always be whatever the value was when the page was loaded, until it gets to the $("#command").submit(); line, then it will be whatever the user has entered.

```
var newcomments = document.getElementById("currComments").value;
var currentcomments = newcomments.length;
alert("currentcomments = " + currentcomments + " newcomments = " + newcomments);
    $("#command").submit();
    var newcomments = document.getElementById("currComments").value;
var currentcomments = newcomments.length;
    alert("currentcomments = " + currentcomments + " newcomments = " + newcomments);
```

I have tried many different ways to check the length, including functions for key presses etc, and none of those worked, yet none of them threw any errors.

I appreciate your help in advance, thank you very much.

EDIT for clarity:

The functions that I have tried have done nothing. For example, if I add in onkeydown='return maxLength(this,"30");' to the textarea block, and the function

```
function maxLength(field,maxChars)
{
   if(field.value.length >= maxChars) {
      event.returnValue=false; 
      alert("more than " +maxChars + " chars");
      return false;
     }

}
```

This does nothing. The user can still type and submit the form.

With the alert box where I get the document.getElementById (when the user hits the submit button), the value received is the initial value of form on load of the page. A user can change the value in the text area, but the value in the alert box will always be the initial value in the box.

I should also mention this is a .jsp page.

Comment: It would probably help people to help you if you would be a little more specific about exactly how the things you've tried don't work.

Comment: Pointy, I edited the page for clarity. Thank you.

Comment: You're passing "30" as a string instead of 30 as a number. That makes a significant difference. Also note that setting `event.returnValue` to `false` only works in Internet Explorer. In other browsers, you have to call `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Pointy, I added event.preventDefault(); and passed 30 as a number, and I still am having no luck. The program seems to only recognize changes on the submission of a form, but (due to the Christmas week) nobody is around to explain how or why.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's a .jsp page at all; by the time it gets to the browser it's HTML.  I'll work up a jsfiddle; give me a sec ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here are some problems:

- `event` is not a global variable in all browsers.  Your `<textarea>` tag should look like this:

  ```
  <textarea onkeypress='return checkMaxLength(event, this, 30)'></textarea>
  ```
- The name "maxLength" appears to be problematic in Firefox.  I changed the name to "checkMaxLength" for that reason.
- The way to prevent the default action is different in standards-compliant browsers than it is in IE.  In those browsers, you have to call the method "preventDefault()" from the event object.  Thus:

  ```
  event.returnValue = false;
  if ('preventDefault' in event) event.preventDefault();
  ```